# Hibernate cache while updating

Tags: java, hibernate, session, caching

Need I care about hibernate session cache while I am doing just insert(write) operations?

Ignore what's down, just to meet SO quality standard:

```
    BiteMe bite=new BiteMeToo("");
bite=null;
bite.letsBite(); //NullPointerException
```

Comment: what is your question? please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never ever read from the DB during the same session/transaction and do not use extended persistence contexts, you do not have to care about cache contents.